# Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, segmentation-fault

I am working on xamarin ios app and trying to push a ViewController in a simple manner but after repeating the process of (push and go back, push and go back,..) i got an error.

Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries

I couldn't be able to find any kind of help regarding this error
[image: here is the actual image of error]

please share if anyone has the solution for this

I am using Visual studio for mac version 7.3.3 (build 5)

[image: Here are my details of xamarin ios version]

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Further context will be needed.

Comment: what kind of context do you want? @AluanHaddad

Comment: How you construct the ViewController that you pushed. Whether it is not be released when you pop back?

Comment: @hmali I am getting similar error while running app in device from visual studio. Did you found any solution for this ?

Comment: @ViralNarshana in my case i was doing some really silly stuff in my base class, this error occurs when your UI code is not managed well.
so take a look at your UI code e.g creating views and managing them using code .. try to figure out UI issue

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still having this issue.

Since this error message is not informative at all. What worked for me was getting my main page's `InitializeComponent()` method call into a try/catch, then reading the full exception message.

basically, this:

```
public MainPage()
        {
            try
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); // Optional: A breakpoint in here
            }
        }
```